# Why does Colonel Landa wear a chevron on his right arm?

Tags: props, inglourious-basterds

In the movie *Inglourious Basterds*, Colonel Landa, wears a chevron on his right arm.

I thought only NCOs would wear chevrons on their uniforms. Does anyone know why Landa wears it as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't checked, but I thought Landa had a Honor Chevron for the Old Guard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honour_Chevron_for_the_Old_Guard

> The Honour Chevron for the Old Guard (Ehrenwinkel der Alten Kämpfer) was a Nazi Party decoration worn by members of the SS. The silver chevron, which was worn on the upper sleeve on the right arm, was authorised by Adolf Hitler in February 1934. All members of the SS who had joined the Allgemeine SS, the NSDAP, or any other party organisation prior to 30 January 1933, were entitled to wear the insignia.
>
> Qualification was later extended to include any SS personnel who were former members of the Nazi Security services, the Ordnungspolizei (order police) and the Wehrmacht, if they fulfilled certain conditions.

In a reference picture, you can see high ranking officials with the chevron in the same position: Reinhard Heydrich, Heinrich Himmler, and Karl Wolff.

There are goofs for various uniforms worn in the movie but the chevron isn't cited as one of them.

Similarly, Obersturmbannfuhrer Max Seela, who served in SS military units from early 1930's, can be seen with the same chevron in the photo on this page:

https://military-history.fandom.com/wiki/Max_Seela

Comment: I see, a symbol of tradition. Similar to British Grenadier and Calvalry units, where they no longer toss grenades in the old way or do they ride horses into battles.

Comment: @YuZhang It's more of a recognition of "original" Nazis as opposed to those who only joined after the party took power. In the movie it shows that Landa has been committed to Nazi ideas for a long time. (If the rest of the movie did not tell you that already)

Comment: Note that the chevron was only established after it could no longer be earned, so there wasn't a tradition of wearing it (as opposed to, say, the grenadiers' bearskins)

Comment: Or, to avoid sounding too positive (the word "idea" is just one letter away from "ideal"): that chevron was there to be able to differentiate the true lunatics from the opportunists that joined after the Nazis came to power?